# SQl from concatenation to parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have this sql connection with concatenated strings query and I would like to change it to parameters. I am starting coding on my own and I do not have many reference. Tried googling around but I have not found something clear enough to me.

```
public bool DBAuthenticate(string strUsername, string strPassword)
{
    string sqlstring;
    sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM credentials WHERE [Username]='" + strUsername + "' AND [Password]='" + strPassword + "'";
    string getconnstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WTAConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getconnstring);
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlstring,conn);
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader;
    conn.Open();
    reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
        return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

can someone please show me how to modify the code to change the query from concatenation to parameters? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use parameters, you need to change your statement as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM credentials WHERE [Username]=@username AND [Password]=@password
```

It then contains two parameters (@username and @password) that you need to provide the values for in the command. You can do this with the [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
// ...
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlstring,conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", strUsername);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader;
// ...
```

Please also note that you should always dispose the connection, commands and readers reliably, so adding some `using` blocks will help:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getconnstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    using(SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlstring,conn))
    {
        // ...
        using(SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you a lot also for the advices.

Comment: @Nullbyte could you please explain me how this works and not mine version didn't. I have posted the same code. How you didn't get again this message "Unknow method AddWithValue(System.Web.Ui.webcontrols.textbox, string) ?

Comment: @ChristosPaisios your version won't compile because you misspelled `Parameters`, not because there was anything wrong with `AddWithValue`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM credentials WHERE [Username]=@UserName AND [Password]=@Password";
```

After the declaration of comm object, write this:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@UserName,strUsername));
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParamter(@Password,strPassword);
```

Comment: it give me two errors. "Unknow method AddWithValue(System.Web.Ui.webcontrols.textbox, string) of system data sql client.sqlparameter collection

Comment: I updated my post. Please try this one and let me know.

Comment: This still won't compile because the `Parameters` property is misspelled. There's no problem with the [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) method