# Getting "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to delete a row in a database through a grid view, however, I am receiving this error: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

```
 protected void ClientDataGrid_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PADSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);    
    string client_code = ClientDataGrid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["client_code"].ToString();
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from client where client_code=" + client_code, con);
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    if (result == 1)
    {
        ClientDataGrid.DataBind();
        Label1.Text = "Deleted successfully";
    }
}

protected void ClientDataGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{       
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string client_code = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "client_code"));
        Button lnkbtnresult = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("ButtonDelete");
        if (lnkbtnresult != null)
        {
            lnkbtnresult.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return deleteConfirm('" + client_code + "')");
        }
    }

}
```

Specifically getting the error on this line

```
    string client_code = 
    ClientDataGrid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["client_code"].ToString();
```

Comment: What does the debugger give you for `e.RowIndex` and for the size of `ClientDataGrid.DataKeys.Count` ?

Comment: Show also the aspx code of the GridView

Comment: How do I do that, im new to c#

Comment: @AdolfBernardMoncawe: set a breakpoint in that line and use the debugger, you can inspect values for example in the quick watch window

Comment: Unrelated: You should be `using( SqlConnection ... )` and don't build your query through string concatenation. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/22782553/982149

Comment: @BadMiscuit it says e.rowIndex 0

Comment: @AdolfBernardMoncawe And what about the size of `ClientDataGrid.DataKeys` (when debugging, hover your mouse on `DataKeys` then look for `Count`) ?

Comment: @AdolfBernardMoncawe: now compare that with `ClientDataGrid.DataKeys.Count`. I guess it is 0 which means it's empty and you cannot access the first item(index 0). Have you set the `DataKeyNames` property of the grid?

Comment: @BadMiscuit how do I check the the size of ClientDataGrid.DataKeys?

Comment: @AdolfBernardMoncawe I edited my comment

Comment: @BadMiscuit yes I set it

Comment: @AdolfBernardMoncawe set what ? Pretty sure, as @TimSchmelter said, that you have an empty `DataGrid`. Make sure that you are doing a correct databinding

Comment: i set the datakeys to the property of my datagrid

Comment: @AdolfBernardMoncawe But is it empty ?

Comment: no its not empty, i am able to display the records on my datagrid

Comment: I just solved it, I was using datakeys="client_code" instead of datakeynames="client_code". Thank you guys